# JSF Menus not getting displayed

Tags: jsf, include, menu, tomahawk, jspinclude

I am having menu.jsp the contents are as follows

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk" prefix="t" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
<html>
<head>
  <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>MyFaces - the free JSF Implementation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/pages/css/basic.css" />
</head>
<body>
<f:view>

  <jsp:include page="menucontents.jsp" /> 
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

The Contents for the menucontents.jsp are as follows

```
<f:subview id="menucontents">
    <f:loadBundle basename="com.cpc.resources.menu" var="menu"/>
    <t:div id="hNav_outer">
        <t:panelNavigation2 id="nav1" layout="list" itemClass="off" activeItemClass="on" openItemClass="on"
                            renderAll="true">
            <t:commandNavigation2 value="#{menu['menu_Home']}" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                <t:commandNavigation2>
                    <f:verbatim>&#8250; </f:verbatim>
                    <t:outputText value="#{menu['menu_Home']}"/>
                </t:commandNavigation2>
            </t:commandNavigation2>
            <t:commandNavigation2 value="#{menu['menu_admin']}" style="padding-left: 150px;">
                <t:commandNavigation2>
                    <f:verbatim>&#8250; </f:verbatim>
                    <t:outputText value="#{menu['menu_admin_change_password']}"/>
                </t:commandNavigation2>
                <t:commandNavigation2>
                    <f:verbatim>&#8250; </f:verbatim>
                    <t:outputText value="#{menu['menu_admin_forgot_password']}"/>
                </t:commandNavigation2>
            </t:commandNavigation2>

        </t:panelNavigation2>
    </t:div>
</f:subview>
```

When I call menu.jsp for some reason I am not able to view the menus which I have configured I only see "› › › " in the browser.

when I do a view source I see the following html

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>MyFaces - the free JSF Implementation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cpcnew/pages/css/basic.css" />
</head>
<body>



<f:subview id="menucontents">
    <f:loadBundle basename="com.cpc.resources.menu" var="menu"/>
    <t:div id="hNav_outer">
        <t:panelNavigation2 id="nav1" layout="list" itemClass="off" activeItemClass="on" openItemClass="on"
                            renderAll="true">
            <t:commandNavigation2 value="#{menu['menu_Home']}" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                <t:commandNavigation2>
                    <f:verbatim>&#8250; </f:verbatim>
                    <t:outputText value="#{menu['menu_Home']}"/>
                </t:commandNavigation2>
            </t:commandNavigation2>
            <t:commandNavigation2 value="#{menu['menu_admin']}" style="padding-left: 150px;">
                <t:commandNavigation2>
                    <f:verbatim>&#8250; </f:verbatim>
                    <t:outputText value="#{menu['menu_admin_change_password']}"/>
                </t:commandNavigation2>
                <t:commandNavigation2>
                    <f:verbatim>&#8250; </f:verbatim>
                    <t:outputText value="#{menu['menu_admin_forgot_password']}"/>
                </t:commandNavigation2>
            </t:commandNavigation2>

        </t:panelNavigation2>
    </t:div>
</f:subview>



<script type="text/javascript"><!--

    function getScrolling()
    {
        var x = 0; var y = 0;if (self.pageXOffset || self.pageYOffset)
        {
            x = self.pageXOffset;
            y = self.pageYOffset;
        }
         else if ((document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollLeft)||(document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop))
        {
            x = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
            y = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }
         else if (document.body) 
        {
            x = document.body.scrollLeft;
            y = document.body.scrollTop;
        }
        return x + "," + y;
    }

//--></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am very close yet so far would appreciate if some one can help me in figuring out the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the *complete* include page? The taglibs are missing in the file header.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk" prefix="t" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
```

That's also why they appeared plain vanilla in the HTML output.

Comment: Did you clean/redeploy/restart? Old file might be still in server work cache.

Comment: Just did that and i still cannot see the formatted menu..... I cannot post the html over here can I post that html in a new question

Comment: But when you add the taglibs, you should not see the JSF tags in generated HTML anymore. Is this true for you?

Comment: Now I dont see the JSF code in the generated HTML I think those are not styled

Comment: Ah OK, then the concrete problem is indeed fixed. As to the new problem, did it originally work when it was not in the include file?

Comment: yes the menus worked very well standalone  the prodblem started when I started to include the  file  in the jsp

Comment: Edit: comment moved to your new question.

Comment: @BalusC the path is the same which was working in the standalone file ... one thing which I need to confirm is where do I need to include that css file in the menu.jsp or menucontent.jsp currently it is there in the menu.jsp